# css-loader- Build is failing

Tags: webpack, css-loader

Dependency versions:

```
"css-loader": "^4.3.0",
"style-loader": "^1.2.1",
"webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file-

```
const path = require('path');
      const config = {
      entry: './src/index.js',
      output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
       filename: 'main.bundle.js'
    },
      module: {
         rules: [
            { use: 'babel-loader', test: /\.js$/ },
            { use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], test: /\.css$/ }
         ]
     }
   }
```

..................................................
I am getting below error:

```
keywords if/then/else require v5 option
(node:15780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function
    at Object.loader (C:\Projects\webpack-test\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:62:27)
```

Comment: this. getResolve is not a function. But it would be really great if you could show the webpack config file :)

Comment: @SergejKlackovskis Below is my webpack config file

const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'main.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { use: 'babel-loader', test: /\.js$/ },
            { use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], test: /\.css$/ }
        ]
    }
}
module.exports = config;

Comment: can you please add it to the question and prettify it. Otherwise it's unreadable...

Comment: @SergejKlackovskis Please check it now

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need to update `webpack` version or downgrade `css-loader`. It might be that you need to do something with `style-loader` as well.

Css loader requires webpack version 4.27.0 and above.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.27.0 || ^5.0.0"
},
```